# How do I make a 2 way confirmation reaction?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How do I make it so that 2 people (me and the person I @) have to press the check button before it confirms?

my code:

````
      let nine = await message.channel.send(embed)

      await nine.react('✅');
      await nine.react('❌');

      const filter1 = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && user.id === message.author.id;
      const col1 = nine.createReactionCollector(filter1, { time: 30000, dipose: true, max: 1 });

      const filter2 = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '❌' && user.id === message.author.id;
      const col2 = nine.createReactionCollector(filter2, { time: 30000, dipose: true, max: 1 });

      col1.on('collect', async r => {
        // the rest of my code```
````

Comment: You can create 2 global variables that track whether the reaction for each have been clicked, then after the timer ends check both variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (you will have to adapt this to *your* code)

```js
const mention = message.mentions.users.first();
const filter = (reaction, user) => [message.author.id, mention.id].includes(user.id) && reaction.emoji.name === '✅'
const reaction = await message.react('✅')
let res = false
let reactions = await message.awaitReactions(filter, {max: 2, time: 30000, errors: ['time']})
const check = reactions.mapValues(r => r.user.id)
if(check.size === 2) res = true
if(res) {
  //they both reacted
} else {
  //they didn’t both react
}
```

If it didn’t work tell me what happened. I didn’t get to test it.

Comment: `else if (!res)` is redundant, the else statement automatically fires when the if-statement is false

Comment: Thank you! I just need to figure out how to make the bot send a message when 2 people react to it. It only responds to the else part